# OS X program doesn't run outside IDE

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, debugging

My app builds with  no errors or warnings, and runs in XCode 6.2 IDE on OS X 10.10.2. Outside the IDE, the icon flashes and nothing else. I don't know where to start debugging, or what to present here.

The log shows:

dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
   Dyld Error Message:

```
 Library not loaded: @rpath/ORSSerial.framework/Versions/A/ORSSerial
```

Referenced from:     /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ERCMac-  blselhcftusiiybindvklfltassg/Build/Products/Debug/ERCMac.app/Contents/Mac  OS/ERCMac
    Reason: image not found

That framework has disappeared.

Comment: Take a look at the system logs in Console.app

Comment: usually it's a problem with pathes. Your app expects certain files (resources/libraries) to be in certain locations but when started from a different working directory, they are not accessible.

Comment: You may be correct. There is a subproject and a 3rd party framework, the framework gets copied into the application bundle, as do the resources. I'm unsure where it all should go.